# Query Using CASE WHEN in Apache Flink's Table API

Tags: mysql, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am using Flink's Table API. I would like to use `CASE WHEN` in a Table API query.
My query uses three fields: `routeid, startlocation, distance` and I want to use a `CASE WHEN` clause to identify factors based on the `distance` value which are conditions required to satisfy based on `routeid`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT 
  routeid, 
  startlocation, 
  CASE WHEN (routeid=1) AND (distance > 0 AND distance <= 250) THEN 'oneday-distance'
```

Is this possible with Flink's Table API? If yes, how can is be done?

Comment: why you don't put all these conditions in WHERE clause?

Comment: My dataset is large & importantly I have multiple conditions for satisfying classes...If I use CASE WHEN, it will be an optimized query...I also want to use UPDATE statement..

Answer (score 0):

The Table API of the latest Flink version 1.0.3 does not support `CASE WHEN` clauses.

For the next release (Flink 1.1.0), the Table API is reworked, extended, and will support `CASE WHEN` clauses. We can try the 1.1-SNAPSHOT version to try the feature. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @FabianHueske Could you pls give the correct case when in: `select("o_orderdate.substring(0,4) as o_year, volume, (when(n_name.like('%BRAZIL%'),volume)) as case_volume")`

Comment: Hey @Fabian, was this removed from more recent versions of Flink SQL? Looking through the 1.10 docs and can't find anything on it.

Comment: Ah, found it -- are there any good examples of this in the Flink docs?

Comment: I'm only aware of this one: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/functions/systemFunctions.html#conditional-functions
But I think this is pretty much standard SQL so there should be plenty of examples in the web like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp